# How to join two tables in Lumen framework?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 2 tables, `users` (with telephone as a primary key) and `address` (with telephone as a foreign key). I add one row in table `users` and want to select users combined with addresses:

This is my code:

```
$login =users::where('users.telephone',$telephone)
->leftJoin('alamat', 'users.telephone', '=', 'address.telephone')
->first();
```

and the result:

```
{"telephone":null,"name":"mr.a","address":null}
```

Why column `telephone` is `null` and how to fix it?

Comment: We would probably need to see your data to give an exact answer, but a `LEFT JOIN` can, and often does, result in columns from the right side of the left join showing up null, if the left side of the join, in this case the telephone number, did not match to anything in the right table.

Comment: Whats the relationship between the two? (1-1 or 1-M)? Why dont you leverage Eloquent ORM?